# Splunk result in Table format

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

Can you please help how to return below splunk result into Table format.

```
Employer details name Jon smith empid:4538938
Employer details name Mac Stone empid:4538939
Employer details name David smith empid:4534458
```

splunk Output in table format

```
Name          Empid
Jon smith     4538938
Mac Stone     4538939
David smith   4534458
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't already have anything parsing the information into fields, then you could apply a regex with [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.2.0/SearchReference/Rex) to extract data into fields, and then plot as a table with the [`table`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.2.0/Viz/TableFormatsGenerate) command:

```
| rex field=Message "Employer details name (?<name>.*) empid:(?<empid>\d+)"
| table name empid
```

Comment: @MadsHanes  your answer is very close. just missing field=Message. I have updated correctly so it should help to someone.

Comment: Well, you didn't indicate that your event info was in the `Message` field in your question. The default is to target `_raw` which is the full event. But if you know your data is in the `Message` field, then it makes sense to apply that for your needs.